# What ":" means in the tree view of android project dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management

When I view the tree view of my android project's dependencies, I see the following entry:

```
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
|    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.7.0-alpha01
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0
```

If I understand correctly, this means that "androidx.legacy:legacy-support" contains a dependency on "androidx.core:core", and so on

There are also other entries in this tree like

```
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.70 -> 1.4.30 (*)
+--- :mopub-chartboost-adapters-8.2.0.3
```

Please advice what does ":" symbol before "mopub-chartboost-adapters" mean? Does "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib" contains dependency on "mopub-chartboost-adapters"?

Thanks

Comment: Using `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0` as an example, `legacy-support` is part of `androidx.legacy`, so I believe `mopub-chartboost-adapters-8.2.0.3` is part of whatever its parent is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is a local dependency. Check if you have placed an aar for `mopub-chartboost-adapters-8.2.0.3` in a local folder which is consumed by gradle in the `dependencies` section of the `build.gradle` file.

org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib" does not contain a dependency on "mopub-chartboost-adapters": [pom.xml](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.20/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.20.pom)